# I'm storing certain items in my cache which are too expensive to query in realtime. How do I update these cache elements?

Tags: java, caching, thread-safety, ehcache

I need to keep updating the cache element every half an hour to prevent it from being stale. During the update, I need to make sure that the get(element) doesn't return null because I don't want the real time query to rebuild the element because that becomes very expensive and will timeout the real time API. I work in a moderately concurrent environment (~5 req/s).

On an update, I want to be able to still access the old cache element until it is updated. Essentially, I don't want the cache to return null and eventual consistency on an update is completely fine with me. How can I achieve something like this using ehcache?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support in Ehcache for this exact scenario. You will have to implement it yourself by handling expiry and update outside of the cache.

Another alternative could be to use *read-through* that is having the cache block on a get while it computes the value, so that other readers wait instead of recomputing the value as well.

This is however not 100% your requirement since you will block instead of returning a slightly outdated value.

Comment: Yeah, blocking will become a problem because it's a large object and putting into the object itself takes some time. I think one approach would be to replicate the object as A & B. If A is present, then I refresh B and invalidate A after that. When a normal read is occurring, I will simple check A/B and whichever one returns non-null I will use it. If both return non-null, it's fine to use the older one as well. If both return null, then I will be forced to compute, but programatically I don't see a case where this happens unless my cache itself expires which I will take care of